# Spring URI mapping error - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring, uri

I want to get to the home page with this link:

```
 <c:url value="/home/home" var="url"/><a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">Home</a>
```

And the home page is in the home folder.

But instead I have this error in my stacktrace

```
   WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP   
 request with URI [/myapp/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'servlet-
 context'
```

As you can see I was not even clicking on any link with a login url but instead that's what happens. And when I try to do it by typing in manually the home url, it changes to the login url and an error page is shown:

```
 HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available.
```

I really don't know why the login keeps coming up when I'm not requesting it.

My controllers

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLogin(ModelMap model) {
    logger.info("This is the login page {}.");

    return "login";

}

    @RequestMapping(value="/home/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHome(ModelMap model) {

    return "home/home";

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `/home/home` is protected, and you have to log in somehow to be able to access it. Then some kind of authorization filter/interceptor tries to redirect to a login page.

Comment: Yes thanks that's correct I can access the pages if I remove them from the intercept url. The only issue is the authentication.